# Hibernate not saving into join table - ManyToOne and JoinTable relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using SpringBoot 2.0.2 with hibernate 5.2.17 and MariaDB 10.1

Customer:

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends Company {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "company_services",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "companyId", insertable = true, updatable = true),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "serviceId", insertable = true, updatable = true))
    private Service service;
```

Service:

```
@Entity
public class Service {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

With Hibernate log enabled I can see this:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.example.company.Customer
        */ insert 
        into
            `
            companies` (
                ...
            ) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        last_insert_id()
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.example.company.Customer
        */ insert 
        into
            `
            company_service` (
                `serviceId`, `companyId`
            ) 
        values
            (?, ?)
20:43:53.524 TRACE [cid: none] [session: none] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder -- binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [3]
20:43:53.524 TRACE [cid: none] [session: none] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder -- binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [3]
```

But when I confirm the result in the db the companies table is OK but the company_services record does not get saved. 
Is that a known bug? I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not use join table for many to one relationship. It uses a join column for many to one relationship.